# How to get from date value the date, hours and minutes in oracle

Tags: date, oracle10g, extract

I have 2 values date field:

1. 5/22/2013 5:28:48 PM
2. 5/22/2013 5:28:49 PM

How can get from this values only date, hours and minutes: **5/22/2013 5:28 PM**. I don't need seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

If you want a string that represents the date in that particular format

```
to_char( your_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM' )
```

If you want a date that sets the seconds to 0 so that all dates are rounded down to the last minute

```
trunc( your_date, 'MI' )
```

If you want something else (for example, to extract the individual components), you'd need to provide more details to explain exactly what you want returned.